# python check user details against dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

```
usr_pwd = {'adam' : 'Test123', 'alice' : 'Test321'}
u_name = input("Please specify your username: ")
u_pwd = input("Please specify your password: ")
usr_pwd[u_name] = u_pwd
if usr_pwd.get(u_name) == u_pwd:
    print('ok')
```

I'm getting frustrated and need some help. How to check against a dictionary  whether and given username and password combination is valid ? I've found the `get` module but the problem with it is :

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

I have also found this [Simple username and password application in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846407/simple-username-and-password-application-in-python) but the code:

```
 if login in users and passw in users: # login matches password
      print "Login successful!\n"
```

does not work for me ...

Comment: What exactly  is the "problem" with the quoted text?

Comment: Is the problem that bad passwords look correct? You overwrite the good password with the prompted password at `usr_pwd[u_name] = u_pwd`.

Comment: You need to read that linked question again... `if login in users and passw in users:` was the bug.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, please apologize. In fact no matter what username and password I will introduce it will respond with 'ok' because it adds the new key value pair to the directory. Is there any other way to do this except using get?

Comment: In your example, you are checking the password against a canned database of passwords. You don't have any code for a user to register a new password so you shouldn't set the password anywhere. Since this code only verifies, it should not write into the databaes.

Comment: @tdelaney Makes absolutely sense. Is there any other way to accomplish the verify operations e.g. other than using get?

Comment: `get` works. If you remove that one line, you now have a program that verifies a password against a canned dictionary of username/password. The `get` returns `None` if a non-existent username is entered. Your program will treat bad username and bad password the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several popular ways to check information in a `dict` and each has their place. Here are some options

```
usr_pwd = {'adam' : 'Test123', 'alice' : 'Test321'}
u_name = input("Please specify your username: ")
u_pwd = input("Please specify your password: ")

# use get
if usr_pwd.get(u_name) == u_pwd:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('user name or password incorrect')

# check first
if u_name in usr_pwd:
    if usr_pwd[u_name] == u_pwd:
        print('ok')
    else:
        print('bad password')
else:
    print('bad user name')

# try and die
try:
    if usr_pwd[u_name] == u_pwd:
        print('ok')
    else:
        print('bad password')
except:
    print('bad user name')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help.